# error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I'm working on substrate node template and their I have adding a pallet where
I have added `let votes = { Votes{ayes: vec![], nays: vec![]} };`

in my pallet.

for that I have also added `use scale_info::prelude::vec;`

but getting `` error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time its just happens due to dependency issue. put the respective dependency inside the pallet module.